# Firebase realtime database erased

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use Firebase realtime database in my react native app. Most things is being done with REST API cloud functions. Few things in app use directly realtime database. Of late i noticed that for no apparent reason all data in my database was erased. Even parts of database which are no longer in use and are not referenced in source code of my app/cloud functions are gone.

The problem happens with two projects and their databases (production/test). I have to use backups to restore them but it happens again even if nobody uses application (eg. in test environment).

Does anybody have idea what might be the source of this problem? I have parts responsible for removal of some parts of the data but it's impossible that all of the run at once. How do I troubleshoot it? How is it possible to remove all the data at once?

My security rules are as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "version": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    },
    "flatLocations": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": false
    },
    "geoplaces": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": false,
      ".indexOn": "g"
    },
    "locations": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    },
    "locationSubscriptions": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": false
    },
    "profiles": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "subscriptionCodes": {
      ".indexOn": "vendingPointId",
      ".read": false,
      ".write": false
    },
    "usersRoles": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": false
    },
    "usersSubscriptions": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": false
      }
    },
    "vendingPoints": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": false,
      ".indexOn": "vendorId"
    },
    "customersBasicData": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": false
    },
    "notificationTokens": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "scheduled": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": false
    }
  }
}
```

Some data are only added. I have no code to delete them.

Comment: There is no automatic deletion of database in your Firebase Database. If your data disappears, it's either because there is a user, process or client that does this, or because something went inexplicably wrong on the Firebase side. While the latter is always possible, I've never heard of it happening undetected, nor to a complete database, let alone to multiple databases of a single developer. As in: it seems much more likely somebody or something on your side does this.

Comment: So I'd investigate more, change passwords, double-check the rules of your database, etc. If after all of those, you still can't find the cause, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. They may be able to check your project for recent unusual operations.

Comment: Either way: without having more information on your project, the functions, the code, the rules, etc, there is nothing anyone here can do.

Comment: Thank you guys for your assistance. I added security rules to description of my question. I believe they are fine. I'm going to add code to check if some part of data not touched by application is still present in database. If not I'll throw an error and know when the problem occured for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `undefined` used in reference. When you run `admin.database().ref(somethingWhichIsUndefined).remove()`, the whole database is ereased.